# Can't type into html input fields on iOS after clicking twice

Tags: javascript, ios, events, input, touch

I'm experiencing an issue on iOS and I've put up a fiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hk56Q/

If an event listener is added to the document for any touch event (touchstart/touchmove/touchend), like so:

```
function onTouch( e ){};
document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouch, false );
```

that results in the input fields having the following behaviour on iOS:

- First touch: the input gets focus and the user can type correctly into it
- Subsequent touches (with focus on the field already in place): typing doesn't work anymore

I'm experiencing and testing this issue on iOS 5, 5.1 and 6, on both iPad and iPhone (simulators and actual devices).

The only fix seems to be removing the event listener to restore the correct behaviour of the input fields (or to actually never add the listener at all):

```
document.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouch);
```

I also noticed that if there are multiple iframes on the page, and one of them adds the listener to its document, it breaks the other iframe's input fields too.

The fiddle behaves correctly on my Android phone.

Any ideas why is this happening? Or how to have global custom event handlers for touch events in place that don't break the inputs on iOS?

Comment: We've encountered this issue with FastClick and it's being [tracked publicly](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/51). I've also filed a [bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2527401) with Apple based in part on your test case.

Comment: Hey, yeah it's definitely a Safari iOS bug, good job reporting it. I still wonder how this issue remained unnoticed for so long..

Comment: I encountered this bug even on resizing the iframe window by zoom in/out.

Comment: I believe these issues have the same source, namely the fact that first touch screens didnt had gestures, and when they made them available they overwrote the existing interface, making implementing custom gestures nearly impossible. Two solution is to use the gesture events, or to block them and reimplement your own from scratch in case you need them.

Comment: Seems interesting. I am finding a way to fix this now.

Comment: The weird thing is, it works for me :/

Comment: I think you should try jQuery Mobile 1.2.0.

At the side of JSFiddle, tick the option and you will see some changes.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a workaround. Set the focus to the window and then back to the node, in a timeout:

```
function fixIpadTouch(node){
    node.ontouchend=function(e){
        if(document.activeElement===node){
            window.focus();
            setTimeout(function(){
                node.focus();
            },0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe this doesn't have more upvotes. The only working solution out there to this very problem. You're a life saver :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new, how to use this function, can you help to show me detail? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A variation of Terry's answer worked around this Mobile Safari bug (!!!) in my case. Here, '#input' and this code is on the iframe page:

```
var el = $('#input');
el.on('keydown', function() {
  window.focus()
  el.focus()
});
```

The bug triggers in multiple ways but 'keydown' comes through reliably. This makes the next 'keypress' arrive as well.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 should be what you need

PROVE! Before ticking the box:

[image: PROVE(before)]

After ticking the box:

[image: After ticking]