# Phonegap - Unable to type in a textbox within an iframe.

Tags: cordova

I have a Phonegap app that is simple iframe serving a web site within it. Have a very strange issue - there's a certain input field (in this case, a textarea) that you can type in.. until you touch a second time on that textarea. Then, you're unable to type in it again (even thought you should technically still have focus) until you touch somewhere else, then come back to the textarea.

This only seems to happen with this one textarea.

I thought this was an issue specific to the app - until a completely different app (again, phonegap iframe serving a website) had the same issue. In this second instance, it was a plain text input, not a textarea.

Has anyone come across this before? Know what could be causing this issue?

We don't have -webkit-user-select: none; anywhere in our CSS - this seems to be a common related issue.

Comment: Are you using any javascript library such us iscroll? Or do you use javascript for validation en the textfield/textarea? If you put the same code you load on the iframe, but inside the app, does it have the error too? It isn't a good idea to use iframes

Comment: No validation occurring on this textbox. I know using an iframe isn't the best, but the goal is to take an existing web app (which is responsive) and make an app out of it. This seems like the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34731528/5552799 This comment helped me resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like it was an issue related to using an iFrame. I just tried using inAppBrowser (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) instead of an iframe, and it worked like a charm. Also, it seems that performance is a little better!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34731528/5552799

This comment helped me out, add a keydown event to all you input elements

```
var el = $("#input")

el.on("keydown", function () {
    window.focus()
    setTimeout(function () {
        el.focus()
    }, 0)
})
```