# iPad, javascript, every next tap on text input makes it not editable

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a text input. It works fine if I tap on it only once. If i want to change caret position (or just when I click again within box) my caret shows at the end and I can't edit text.

So anytime I want to change something in the middle of text I have to focus on anything else and then try to tap exactly in the place I want to edit.

EDIT:

I have an additional window which is build based on HTML:

```
<div id="input-box" class="col-md-8"></div>
```

In typescript:

```
let inputBox = document.getElementById(`input-box`);
this._input = new Text({
        id: `input`
    }).inject(inputBox);


let textValue = document.getElementById(`input`) as HTMLInputElement;
```

That's it. It works anywhere else. Android, any browser, issue is only in iPad app.

Comment: Please show your code, use [stackoverflow snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Ok, i finally found same question and it's answer works for me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124340/cant-type-into-html-input-fields-on-ios-after-clicking-twice