# Facebook In-App Browser on iOS doesn't handle correctly inputs within iframe

Tags: html, ios, facebook, webview

The issue only occurs on Facebook's In-App Browser (and Messenger) on iOS. Doesn't reproduce on Safari @ iOS, Chrome @ iOS or Facebook's In-App Browser on Android.

When having an input inside an iframe, and when the iframe has `position: fixed;` and is positioned to the bottom of the viewport (i.e. `bottom: 0;`) - the input is focus-able only once.

Once it's being focused, the keyboard pops up, and after closing the keyboard - the page "freezes" and the input cannot be focused again - until the page is being scrolled which release the freeze.

Narrowed it down to the following snippet:

- Website: https://adiramsalem.github.io/ios-iframe-input-bug/
- Source: https://github.com/AdirAmsalem/ios-iframe-input-bug/blob/master/index.html
- Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DDA7GaFKmD69nG51aleZqdYpGM-v9BNW/view

As it only reproduces on Facebook's In-App Browser on iOS, the snippet can be opened via the following Facebook Page: (in the Website section)
https://www.facebook.com/pg/Adirs-Sport-Store-881742425287139/about/

Code:

```html
<iframe style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 100px;" srcdoc="<input/>"></iframe>
```

Anyone encountered a similar issue or has any advice?

Comment: I think the problem is not related to the iframe. Safari iOS has a bug that is referred to as "FastClick", but it might be related to your issue as well (both issues deal with a second click on a textarea). try this fix - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30565613/9220122 and I also recommend reading the comments there.

Comment: thanks for the comment @KarinC but that's a different issue which reproduces under the circumstances mentioned in the question: facebook app's browser, ios, fixed positioned iframe, input being focused, keyboard which when opens moves the input from its original position, and then when closing the keyboard - it leaves the keyboard area non-interactive and the page is kind-of stuck.